# Access "data" object in AJAX request inside success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I access the `data` object used in a `$.ajax()` request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "post.php",
    type:'POST',
    data:{
        el1: $('#el1').val(),
        ...
        el72: $('#el72').val()
    },
    success: function(res,status){
        //
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just saving the data in a variable before your AJAX call then referencing that variable in the success callback?

Comment: Using `$_POST['el1']`

Comment: ^ that will give you the data on the server-side if your server is written in PHP. Are you trying to get the data on the server or access it in your success callback?

Comment: where do you want to access it ??

Comment: @MikeC Yes, creating a variable could be a solution. But I decided to ask just to learn more.

Comment: @Deep in the `success` function.

Comment: `console.log(this.data)`

Comment: @KevinB That works! Can you please write it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: it seems to fail in a fiddle, maybe get vs post?

Comment: @KevinB It works, you just need to make sure the type is POST: https://jsfiddle.net/17t4kfw9/ the `data` field refers to the HTTP body, I guess. If there's a GET with no body, there's no `data` attribute. Also, if you pass in an object like the OP does, you get formdata-formatted `data`, since that's what is in the HTTP body.

Comment: makes sense, because as GET it gets added to the url, and you can pull it from `this.url`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the processed options that you passed into $.ajax from within the success callback using `this`, as long as you didn't bind the function, use an arrow function, or use the context option.

```
console.log(this.data); // for POST
console.log(this.url); // for GET, but you'll have to parse out the url portion
```

You'll notice though that it's in a parameterized string rather than an object now because that's how it is sent to the server. See here for ways to convert it back to an object: [Convert URL parameters to a JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object)

---

I would just use a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable before calling `ajax()`.

```
var formData = {
    el1: $('#el1').val(),
    ...
    el72: $('#el72').val()
};

$.ajax({
    url: "post.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(res,status){
        // do something with formData
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for an answer without using a variable before the ajax. Upvote though.